# Plugging into on_page_change events in testcafe

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm using testcafe to e2e testing, as part of this there's a function that's called whenever a test action results in a page change e.g clicking on links.

I'm looking for a way to not have to do this manually.
Is there a page_change_event in testcafe I can hook into and run said function then?

Any help appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

At present, TestCafe does not have such functionality. 
Please create a suggestion in the [testcafe repository](https://github.com/devexpress/testcafe) and describe in detail your use case.